# Run a command before & after ubuntu apt upgrade & unattended-upgrades

Tags: ubuntu, apt

On an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server I run some process monitors, but I also run apt manually as well as unattended-upgrades for security updates.

This sometimes causes the monitors to report and act on programs that were stopped by apt during apt upgrade.

Is there a way to run a command when unattended-upgrades/apt starts the upgrades (to stop the monitors) and again when unattended-upgrades/apt finishes (to restart the monitors)?

I found `APT::Update::Pre-Invoke` and `APT::Update::Post-Invoke` hooks but the apt *update* step is not the problem, and apt itself does not seem to have any pre/post *upgrade* hooks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three hooks you can use for this:

- `DPkg::Pre-Invoke` is run once, before all the package manipulation sequences in one `apt` invocation;
- `DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs` is also run once, before the package manipulation sequences, after the `Pre-Invoke` hook, and with a list of all the packages which will be installed;
- `DPkg::Post-Invoke` is run once, after the package manipulation sequences.

The documentation isn’t all that clear (do read [`man apt.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html) though), but reading [the source code](https://anonscm.debian.org/git/apt/apt.git/tree/apt-pkg/deb/dpkgpm.cc#n1490) supports the above. Specifying hooks also confirms this (for example, this is how `apt-listbugs` works).

Comment: Works just like I wanted: DPkg::Pre-Invoke is run *once* before the start of all package manipulation sequences for that 'apt upgrade' run, and DPkg::Post-Invoke is run once when they are all completed. Just wanted to clarify that they don't get run before each (any) package.

Comment: Indeed, that’s what I was trying to explain above, but my answer wasn’t clear enough (and that’s what’s not clear in the documentation either).