# What's the equivalent of Pacman's hooks in Apt?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm a decently long-time Arch user, and now I am trying to create something similar to a post-transaction hook on a Debian system for a specific package.

[Hooks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman#Hooks) are commands, or shell scripts ran after installing and/or upgrading and/or removing a package using Pacman. They're used to do some configuring before or after a package has changed.

What's an alternative for this functionality in Apt, and where can I read more about it? I didn't really find much info

Comment: [Run a command before & after ubuntu apt upgrade & unattended-upgrades](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401126/86440) lists the major `apt` hooks, but I’m not sure they would easily map to Pacman-style hooks.